# Events and Callbacks, need to wait before two events triggered and call callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, rxjs, async.js

The code could be simplified to something like that,

```
function start(callback) {
    one.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('one server ready');
    });

    two.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('two connection ready');
    });

    one.connect();
    two.start();
}
```

I need to call that `callback`, after both services getting to ready state. What's the best pattern for that?

**Update:** Ideas how to do that with RxJS are welcome :)

Comment: You should probably use `.once()` rather than `.on()`.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

Comment: async parallel is for another case.. then I'm having a bunch of async functions, that need to be executed and single callback triggered. Here I don't have function, I have eventemitters.

Comment: Just wrap them into async functions and call their callback in the event handler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RxJS way of approaching it would be to use either `zip` or `when/and/thenDo` for the synchronization, and `fromEvent` to manage the `EventEmitter`

```
function ready(ee) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(ee, 'ready');
}

//EITHER
var option1 = Rx.Observable.when(ready(one).and(ready(two))
                                 .thenDo((first, second) => "Both Ready!"));

//OR
var option2 = Rx.Observable.zip(ready(one), ready(two), 
                                (first, second) => "Both Ready!");

option1.take(1).subscribe(() => callback());
```

Answer (score 8):

You asked for promises, let's see how we can convert one time events to promises, aka [promisifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) the emitters:

```
function ready(ee){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        ee.on("ready", resolve); // resolve when ready
    });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
Promise.all([ready(one), ready(two)]).then(function(){
   // both ready here
});
```

You can easily aggregate promises which is very nice :)

Comment: good one. promises of cause are really obvious here.. would be interesting to see some alternatives..)

Comment: @alexanderb alternatives are good. Just keep in mind that promises are the standard and the way forward. Expect more and more APIs to move to them.

Answer (score 1):

**Low-tech**

A low-tech way is to maintain a counter of events and then call the callback when you have received enough:

```
function start (callback) {

    var numSteps = 2;
    var currStep = 0;

    var step = function () {

        currStep++;
        if (currStep === numSteps) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    one.once('ready', () => {

        step();
        console.log('one server ready');
    });

    two.once('ready', () => {

        step();
        console.log('two connection ready');
    });

    one.connect();
    two.start();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know that pattern.. but it looks too clumsy to me. looking for more interesting ideas.

Comment: This pattern is called an "asynchronous semaphore" or just a semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [event-as-promise](https://npmjs.com/package/event-as-promise) package. It convert events into Promise continuously until you are done with all the event processing.

In your case,

```
import EventAsPromise from 'event-as-promise';

const oneReady = new EventAsPromise();
const twoReady = new EventAsPromise();

one.once('ready', oneReady.eventListener);
two.once('ready', twoReady.eventListener);

await Promise.all([one.upcoming(), two.upcoming()]);
```

Simple and cleaner than RxJS in this case.

Answer (score 0):

## With `jQuery ($)`:

```js
$('#greet').one('click', function(evt){
  $(evt.currentTarget).one('click', function(){
    alert('Hi!');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="greet">Greet ONLY on second click.</button>
```

Good Luck...